# Subprocess: calling a program with two input redirects

Tags: python, bash, subprocess, io-redirection

I'm attempting to run the following command where `AAA` and `BBB` are Python variables that contain a bunch of multi-line data.

I'd rather not slow myself down by writing the variables to disk. It seems like `subprocess.Popen` should support this somehow.

```
diff <(echo AAA) <(echo BBB)
```

I know that there is a subtlety to how this works on the shell level that I'm not grasping that would probably make this a snap.

How do I call one shell executable in Python, using subprocess, with two input redirects that contain Python variables?

Comment: `Popen()`'s return value has a `stdin` attribute (assuming that you passed `stdin=PIPE` when you created the object).  Call `.write()` on this twice, passing it your `AAA` and `BBB` values.

Comment: Are you trying to call `diff` from Python? Or are you trying to feed the output of two Python scripts into `diff` in the shell? I don’t quite understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: `<(echo AAA)` is a process substitution, not a redirection. Bash runs `echo AAA` asynchronously and redirects its stdout to a FIFO, then substitutes `<(echo AAA)` with the FIFO's path. Run `set -x; diff <(echo AAA) <(echo BBB)` and you'll see that the command that's actually executed is something like `diff /dev/fd/63 /dev/fd/62`.

Comment: I guess you can do the same thing in Python using FIFOs.

Comment: If you want to get a diff using Python, did you try using [difflib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html)?

Comment: BONUS POINTS to oguz ismail!

Comment: jasonharper, i tried calling 'communicate' twice to no avail, EOF from the first write closed the handle. I think that will be the same for write. I'll use FIFO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this achieve what you wanted ?

```
import os
import subprocess

os.environ['aaa'] = """This is python multiline data containing
AAA"""
os.environ['bbb'] = """This is python multiline data containing
BBB"""
process = subprocess.Popen(['/bin/bash', '-c', 'diff <(echo "$aaa") <(echo "$bbb")'])
process.communicate()
```

Comment: I ended up using difflib I think this would have also worked.